# TCL : what is the major drawbacks of source command over package command

Tags: tcl

The `source` command reads the file content and executes it line by line.

Packages also internally uses source command.

Somebody says that source command having the drawbacks, my question is the same drawbacks won't come when we are using the package (package require) command.

I analysed alot on this, but i did not get full clarification regarding this.

I want to know the following things:

1. What are the drawbacks of source command?
2. Why we come for packages?
3. What are the drawbacks of package?
4. Why we go for Namespace?

Comment: Probably a little much for a single question :)

Comment: 1. Who said that source has drawbacks, and what are the drawbacks? 2. What are the results of your analyzation?

Comment: And again: namespaces and packages are different things. Like apple and pears. Packages aim to solve the file managment, while namespace aim to solve name clashes at runtime. They are not incompatible, in fact a fruit salad is better than an apple or a pear alone.

Answer (score 1):

***Packages are higher-level concepts than source files***; when you do `package require` that gets converted internally into a `source` of the appropriate file (or files) that implements the package. It might also `load` a shared library that was implemented in C, and other more complicated options are possible. You don't have to know what it is doing.

Namespaces are orthogonal, in that they don't map at all to source files. They're just script-visible things for defining a mapping from names to entitles (commands, variables, …)

By *convention*, packages should use a namespace with the same name as the package's name; this is not universally followed (and nobody is about to change that; *many* existing packages predate the namespace mechanism and breaking them just to enforce the convention would be very user-hostile). You are encouraged to follow the convention as it is a useful way to simplify things; it makes things easier for users of your code.

Comment: Your question indicates that you're not ready to deal with the more complex features of namespaces, but the core of the concept of a namespace in Tcl is that name mapping.